# How to extract branch name in the PR workflow?

Tags: github-actions

Here is my sample GitHub workflow:

```
name: APP Build
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/test

jobs:
  check-environment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch name
        shell: bash
        run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}| sed 's/\//-/g')"
        id: extract_branch
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: check-environment
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: echo ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}
```

I have these 3 problem:

- Once PR is created and I push some changes, this triggered 2 builds. One for the `pull_request:` and one for `push:`. How to make sure when both is `on:` condition is met then trigger only 1 build?
- When build is trigger by the push on branch. I get the output of `echo ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}`: `feature-test`. Which is expected but when build is trigger by pull request same `echo ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}` becomes refs-pull-2-merge. How to still get branch name for the pull request?
- How to make job name test run only for Pull request build. For Push only check-environment should be run and for pull request both the job should run. I know there is if condition but how to make it run for pull request(new PR and update on PR)

Answer (score 1):

> Once PR is created and I push some changes, this triggered 2 builds. One for the pull_request: and one for push:. How to make sure when both is on: condition is met then trigger only 1 build?

Your workflow is triggered multiple times because `on` conditions work as `OR` and not as `AND`. Therefore it will trigger for each event condition that is configured.

*Example: You cannot create a `pull request` without `pushing` your commits into the source branch, so both events conditions will be met in that case.*

To trigger the workflow only for a specific event, you would need to add **types** to the configured events ([here are the available ones for PR](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request)).

You can also keep the same triggers, but add **conditions** for each job (I give some examples in the 3rd point below) according to your context.

---

> When build is trigger by the push on branch. I get the output of echo
> `${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}`: feature-test. Which is
> expected but when build is trigger by pull request same echo `${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}` becomes refs-pull-2-merge. How
> to still get branch name for the pull request?

The `refs/pull/<number>/merge` is a reference created by GitHub to keep track of what would happen if a pull request was merged. It references the merge commit between `refs/pull/<number>/head` and the destination branch (e.g. `master`).

In your case here, one way to get the base branch on a PR event could be by doing something like this:

```yaml
- name: Step that prints name of pull request's base branch
  if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
  run: echo "Pull request's base branch is: ${BASE_BRANCH}"
  env:
    BASE_BRANCH: ${{ github.base_ref }}
```

For more details, see the [documentation on the github context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context)

---

> How to make job name test run only for Pull request build. For Push only check-environment should be run and for pull request both the job should run. I know there is if condition but how to make it run for pull request(new PR and update on PR)

You could use something similar to condition used on the answer above, at a `step level` or at the `job level`, according to what you want to do. Example:

**If event is PR**

```yaml
   if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
```

**If event is PUSH**

```
   if: github.event_name == 'push'
```

**If event is PUSH `AND` PR (use `||` for `OR`)**

```yaml
   if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event_name == ‘push’
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Regarding this "However, if you already have an opened pull request and push a new commit to the branch, only the push event will trigger." I have an open PR and push a new commit but still, it's triggering both events which result into multiple workflow.

Comment: You're right, this happens because there is not sub-type informed on the [pull_request event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request). Therefore it will also trigger is the pull request is edited. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I updated my question. Now I have described sub-type but still getting multiple builds. There should be a way by which if a PR is created already then only one event should get triggered for PR and Push

Comment: If you just leave the `[opened]` type, wouldn't it work as you expect? (using PR condition on creation, and PUSH on others?)

Comment: Actually no, For push we just build the app. For PR we want to build, deploy and test. 

And after PR is created, every changes needs to build, deploy and test. I think there is no way to do that

Comment: Also, Is there any option that I can trigger a Push build only if the commit message contains *build*?

Comment: I believe you can as the commits are stored inside the GITHUB CONTEXT when the event is a push, using something like `if: contains(github.event.commits.message, 'build')`. It will only work for [push events](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/81f41fb8b53a0bd3d63856f919e501c2), not for [pull_request events](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/e53ec9b6bc783cce184bd1eec263799d)